# Multiline Regex bar the last line

Tags: php, regex

Im trying to create a regex that captures the last character before a new line to check if a comma is the last character of the line as you would see in a postal address for validation errors as I want to enforce the inclusion of commas.

eg.

Address Line 1,
Address Line 2,
Address Line 3,
Address Line 4,
Region,
Postcode

The information is to be added through a text area but I can't seem to be able to figure it out as I am not very good with regex. So far I have got:

```
/\w\n/igm
```

but this captures all the lines plus any line ending with a special character would pass validation whereas all lines bar the last should end with a comma. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

cheers Callum

Comment: Try `preg_match('/,[\r\n]/',$your_string)`.

Comment: Hi Ismael and thanks for answering, I couldn't get your answer to work for me at first but by replacing preg_match with preg_match_all I got it to work exactly as I wanted it to. thanks once again cheers Callum

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. This was too easy to be an answer. You can answer the question yourself and 2 days later mark it as the Accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Im trying to create a regex that captures the last character before a new line

You can just use this regex:

```
/,$/m
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bD2oG8/2)

Comment: Hi and thanks for answering, The downside to this is that it picks up any character at the end of a line whereas I'm trying to find lines that do or do not end with a comma. thanks Callum

Comment: ***do or do not end with a comma** means you want to match any character before EOL right? If you want only lines ending with comma then use `/,$/m`

Comment: Hi Anubhava, I got it to work using the answer above. Thanks for your time cheers Callum

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will find all the errant lines, then add a comma where needed.

Globally find: `([^,\r\n])(?<!Postcode)(\r?\n|\z)`
and replace: `$1,$2`

Should do the trick.

```
 # ([^,\r\n])(?<!Postcode)(\r?\n|\z)

 ( [^,\r\n] )         # (1), Last char before linebreak or EOS
 (?<! Postcode )      # Not 'Postcode' behind
 ( \r? \n | \z )      # (2), Linebreak or EOS
```